# How to refresh JTable binding to a MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I've been looking for a solution for about two hours and, though I've found several questions similar to this one I couldn't understand how to deal with my problem. Guess it's because I'm not good enough at Java programming to get the answers.
So what I'm trying to do is having a JTable to automatically refresh its data (wich are bound to a MySQL DB) whenever the DB's table is edited.

I know that I have to deal with the TableModel (I really can't understand what is it), but I can't understand how to know which one my JTable is working with, because all I get from the "Table contents" menu is TableModel: Bound.

Help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your concern is knowing when the database table is edited.  There's no automatic way to know.  You have to read the table every 5 minutes (as an example time period) and determine if anything changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use observer design pattern with DAO